# Sage 200 workspace creation - linq

Tags: linq

New to stack but hoping for some slight help.
I am new to the linq coding language but I have programmed in vba, some sql etc.
We had a company produce some dev work to create various new bespoke screens/fields into our sage 200 extra (an extra 20 to 30 data contexts with each containing multiple fields and varying primary keys which don't match between them. I want to show list views through workspaces from 2 or 3 different data contexts but I am struggling how to join the data contexts so that the list view will show all data from the fields of the 3 data contexts, however, I am struggling with the correct linq coding to join the data contexts, below is the code from one of them but this is showing purely the headers with no data, so I assume this is due to the wrong 'join' statement.

Please can you correct or give tips for the below, so I can further understand how linq works. The example shows the standard sage 200 data context SOPOrderReturns from sage 200 as well as the bespoke we added called I8TFWorkFlows, which I need to join to display along with SOPOrderReturns:

```
 var q = from SOP in cxt.SOPOrderReturns
   from WF in cxt.I8TFWorkFlows

 select new

 {

 SOP.DocumentNo,
 SOP.DocumentDate,
 DocumentStatus = SOP.DocumentStatus.Name,
 SOP.SOPOrderReturnID,
 WF.I8TFWorkflowID,
 WF.ColourProofRequestedDate,
 WF.ColourProofApprovedDate,
 WF.ColorProofSentDate,
 WF.AmendmentToOrder,

 };

 return q;
```